# How to unbind kendo datasource from ajax call and work programmatically

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a kendo.ui.grid. I want to download grid data with ajax when it is initially rendered. Next, I want to unbind the grid from ajax calls and to add new records and remove existing programmatically. What is important, I want to filter and sort data at any moment, of course working on local copy, without sending ajax request. Eventually, I want to (maybe with button) send all data to server in order to save changes in database. Could you please provide some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check their ["bind with local data"](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/local-data.html) example on their demos website. What you can do is create your own JavaScript AJAX call that requests the data in JSON format from the server when the page first loads. Then on success, bind the data with the grid with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //jquery get https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(jsonData) {
            //bind to the grid
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: jsonData,
                    /*****DATA CONFIG OPTIONS****/
                },
                /*****GRID CONFIG OPTIONS****/
            });
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you may code something like below to request data in json format and store into a variable

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("POST", "your url", false);
xhReq.send(null);
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText); //data would be store in var jsonObject 

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource:jsonObject 
});
```